# How many parents I need provide as __declspec(export) in headers for client when building dll?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, dll

I writing a little engine for myself. And I don't know how provide minimal number of headers and info from engine for client code. All that user needs is Processor template class and two public methods, and methods from IProcessor which user must override. The questions are below.

```
#ifdef __ARENGINE_ON_WORK__
    #define DLL_SPEC __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_SPEC 
#endif

template<typename T, typename... masks>
class Processor : public ProcessorBase
{
public:
    DLL_SPEC static BitMask Mask()
    {
        static const BitMask mask = FormMask((masks::Mask())...);
        return mask;
    }

    DLL_SPEC BitMask GetMask() override
    {
        return Mask();
    }

private:
    template<typename... masks>
    static BitMask FormMask(const masks&... args)
    {
        BitMask resultMask = 0;
        std::vector<BitMask> vec = { args... };
        for (auto item : vec) resultMask |= item;
        return resultMask;
    }
};

class DLL_SPEC ProcessorBase : public EngineStorable, public IProcessor
{
public:
    ~ProcessorBase();

private:
    void NotifyProcessorDeleting();
};
```

1. Need I mark Processor class as DLL_SPEC?
2. Need I mark ProcessorBase as DLL_SPEC?
3. Need I provide ProcessorBase header file for client code? If yes, how many parents of inheritance hierarchy I need provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Processor code is inline, it is not necessary to mark `Processor` class as DLL_SPEC - all code will be instantiated in client module.
The only method which will be imported is `~ProcessorBase()` - so mark just this method.
By the way, exporting destructor may be unsafe if your DLL and a client module uses different versions of C runtime library. In this case add exported method `void destroy()` and call `delete this` in the implementation.